# What does Class Complexity mean in Weka?

Tags: data-mining, entropy, weka

When running Weka on my dataset, in the results printout I get the following rows:

```
Class complexity | order 0           44138.7117 bits      8.9205 bits/instance
Class complexity | scheme            46697.7417 bits      9.4377 bits/instance
Complexity improvement     (Sf)      -2559.03   bits     -0.5172 bits/instance
```

What does Class complexity mean? And what is the difference between "order 0" and "scheme"? Does it have to do with entropy and information gain?

Comment: What is Weka? What kind of statistical analysis are you conducting? What are the nature of your data (i.e. variables, and possible values taken by each). What is your sample size? What is your study design?

Comment: Weka is a tool for data mining [link]http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ . I am trying to perform regression on up to 13 continuous variables with samples sizes ranging from 5000-15000. The idea behind Weka is that you can switch between several different types of analysis, e.g. linear regression, neural networks, SVM:s etc etc

Comment: @Alexis What I've found so far is this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.weka/33141) where it seems to equal to entropy in the discrete case. But I'm not sure how it applies in the continuous case and if it's even meaningful for regression. The fact that complexity goes up instead of down is not a good sign...